# JSF: actionListener method never called

Tags: jsf, netbeans-6.9, actionlistener

I saw this [question too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-is-not-being-invoked/2120183), but I still can't make it work. I realized that when I calling a method it have red circle ([image: aaaa]) like regular method that returns void (Netbeans IDE).
Here is aaaa method:

```
public void aaaa(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
}
```

Is this a normal for Netbeans IDE? Anyway, normal or not, my method is never called. Just to mention I don't have nested forms!

Comment: What is the memory scope of your bean if I may ask?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the question which you found [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-is-not-being-invoked/2120183), the following must be made sure for an `actionListener`:

- Ensure that the argument of an `actionListener` method is `javax.faces.event.ActionEvent` and not something else such as `java.awt.ActionEvent` which the average IDE autosuggests as 1st match.

Is there by the way any particular reason you're using `actionListener` instead of `action` here?

Comment: I am using the right Class - javax.faces.event.ActionEvent. Actually I make it work putting immediate="true" attribute. Can you please explain me why it work with it, and not without.

Comment: Then you've a validation/conversion error in an input element which is not covered by `immediate="true"`. Check point 3 of the answer on the question which you found. Add `<h:messages/>` to be notified of any missing errors, or read the server logs.